# Does spread spectrum clocking degrade a CPU's performance and cause it to operate at higher temperatures?

Tags: cpu, performance, temperature, clockspeed, cpu-temperature

Does spread spectrum clocking cause a CPU to operate at higher temperatures? If so, why?

Spread spectrum clocking minutely varies a CPU's clock speed to spread out RFI to meet FCC and EU guidelines.

I disabled spread spectrum in my BIOS, and my CPU is running ~20°C cooler!

I also noticed that disabling spread spectrum sped up my computer. According to [luminaris on Tom's Hardware forum](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/spread-spectrum.299514/#post-1938220), "enabling spread sprectrum actually hurts performance". Why is this?